# How to parse nested keys using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a data structure which have multiple nested keys, key1 and key2.

*The value of key1 and key2 is unknown and will typically be some GUID's.*

How do I get the data out of this structure?

```
"key1":
    {
      "key2": {
           "name1":"value1",
           "name2":"value2",
           "sub1":    
               {
                  "sub1_name1":"sub1_value1",
                  "sub2_name2":"sub2_value2"  
               },
           "name3":"value3"
      }
   }, .... more records following
```

I have the following code that extracts some data but after that I am unable to query the data:

```
admin.database().ref('table_x/').once('value', (snapshot) => {

   console.log(snapshot.key); //table_x

   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

        var key1 = child.key; // this gives key1

        // get key 2
        // get key 2's values, children
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for (key in child) {
  for (innerkey in child[key]) {
    console.log(innerkey);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chickenbeef/ycers98g

Answer (score 0):

Use the library Defiantjs(http://defiantjs.com/) they have a nice implementation of an xslt template to pull in your data set

once you able to loop through your data structure, use the xpath tool provided by the library to run specific queries.

Example of JSON.search

```
 data = [{
"key1": {
  "key2": {
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2",
    "sub1": {
      "sub1_name1": "sub1_value1",
      "sub2_name2": "sub2_value2"
    },
    "name3": "value3"
  }
}}],
res1 = JSON.search(data, "//*[contains(name(), 'key')]/."),
res2 = JSON.search(data, "//*[contains(text(), 'sub')]/..");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/edsonvanwyk/amanp3g0/4/